# How to construct a deque class w/ member functions in it? C++

Tags: c++, function, class, vector, deque

I'm new to C++ and my professor asked us to construct a Deque class and several other classes like Stack and Queue as well.

Below is what I've done so far.

My question is: How to construct/make a function and make it works? For example how exactly could you make a push_front(int) function here? (don't really have to use template, using int is totally fine.)

Only one example would be enough for me to figure out what to do next.

Really appreciate helps.

```
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Deque{
public:
    void push_front(int); //Insertion from left
    void push_back(int x){m_Vector.push_back(x);};//Insertion from right
    void pop_front();//Remove from left
    void pop_back(){m_Vector.pop_back();};//Remove from right
    int getL()const {return m_left;}
    int getR()const {return m_right;}
protected:
    //Protected Data members
    int m_left;
    int m_right;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int length;
    vector<int> m_Vector;
//structure  
};
// Deque member functions definitions


class Queue:private Deque{
public:
    void insertL(int a){push_front(a);};
    int removeR(){return pop_back();};
};

class Stack:private Deque{
public:
    void push(int x){push_front(x);};
    int pop(){return pop_front();};
    bool full(){return m_left == m_right;}
protected:
    using Deque::m_left;
    using Deque::m_right;
};


#endif /* CLASSES_H */
```

UPDATE:

I just made a little function like this,

```
void Deque::push_front(int x){
    m_Vector.insert(m_Vector.begin(),x);
}
```

And I put it right after the Deque class. Could someone tell me if I'm doing it right?

2nd UPDATE:

I got pop_front done like this.

```
void Deque::pop_front(){
    m_Vector.front() = std::move(m_Vector.back());
    m_Vector.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: Were you instructed to use `vector` as the underlying data store?

Comment: Yes I've learned some basic info about vector on google.

Answer (score 1):

`push_front` is incredibly inefficent on `vector` you should generally avoid it. (You have to move every element of the vector to do it).

Given that you have `m_left` and `m_right` I would postulate that your professor wanted you to make a circular buffer within your vector. That does not involve `push_back` or any similar function at all as the actual data values could be some subset of the overall ones and the front and back of your data could be at an arbitrary index, not necessarily the end of the `vector`.

Your `Stack` and `Queue` look fine though, you once you implement the functionality of the `Deque`.

Research circular buffers as a topic, there is plenty online explaining how they work, they are vastly more efficient on an individual operation basis for many workloads but have weird properties around their space usage and more expensive access so aren't provided as the default in vector.

I would recommend taking your time with examples when it comes to those 4 methods, especially when it comes to the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. The`push_front/back`and `pop_front/back`functions are also required by my professor. I'm aware of the fact that `push_front` is inefficient but I just gotta create a function that works that way.

Comment: @XinzeWang: Naming them the same provides confusion. Your `push_back` doesn't have to use vector's `push_back` necessarily. `vector.push_back` is inefficent, yours does not need to be. There are ways to make it efficient by changes how you handle your data within the `vector` by using `vector` as a data storage mechanism alone.

Comment: I got what you mean. Efficiency is not really one of my concerns in this project though. I will try to change it after I got the whole thing done first but thx :))